# Is GRUM authorised by Instagram? They are clearly using the API keys to replicate the app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

App looks shady, but AppSumo has just done a massive sale on it:
http://www.appsumo.com/grum/

Can we start doing this, what's the situation, is Instagram listening to those violations or ignoring them? Curious to replicate this, but not if it'll be shut down within a day. They seem to have been operating for well over a year with great success.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about software licensing, not development.

Comment: Instagram dev support suggests to file platform related questions over here at StackOverflow. Hence I posted it here under their tag.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too, as far as I'm aware posting access isn't part of the API.